# Visual Studio 2013 sticks on splash screen for half an hour

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013. All of them take ages loading up and when they do are very slow. The used to work find but became incredibly slow after I installed a version of Power Tools. I uninstalled this but it has made no difference.

I've run with all of the safemode setup resetsetting options. None of them have made any difference. Safemode starts a bit quicker but I can't do anything like use TFS.

I have produced a log (see record 128 for slow step) and this is an excerpt of where the time is being taken:

```
<entry>
  <record>126</record>
  <time>2015/05/12 15:39:04.522</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>127</record>
  <time>2015/05/12 15:39:04.522</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPackage]</description>
  <guid>{CF6A5C16-83B0-4D04-B702-195C35C6E887}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>128</record>
  <time>2015/05/12 15:57:37.862</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
  <guid>{715F10EB-9E99-11D2-BFC2-00C04F990235}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>129</record>
  <time>2015/05/12 15:57:37.862</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Environment Menu Package]</description>
  <guid>{715F10EB-9E99-11D2-BFC2-00C04F990235}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>130</record>
  <time>2015/05/12 15:57:37.862</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>End package load [Visual Studio Environment Menu Package]</description>
  <guid>{715F10EB-9E99-11D2-BFC2-00C04F990235}</guid>
</entry>
```

Comment: This `Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPackage` appears to be the package with the problem.  Is it always the same package?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. What is this package and how can I remove it?

Comment: You may want to search your registry for the string 'CF6A5C16-83B0-4D04-B702-195C35C6E887'. If it's in the registry then you may want to post the relevant registry data here so that we can compare your results to our systems. My installation has it under: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Profile\LazyImport` for example. If it's been removed from that list then it is possible that this is a module which should be loading in the background but isn't.

Comment: I have it in that location and the equivalent for version 11

Comment: Is that all? I also have this: `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Packages\{cf6a5c16-83b0-4d04-b702-195c35c6e887}]
@="Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPackage"
"InprocServer32"="C:\\Windows\\\\SYSTEM32\\\\MSCOREE.DLL"
"Class"="Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPackage"
"Assembly"="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal,version=12.0.0.0,publicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,culture=neutral"` This is actually in a few places though.

Comment: 7 places in total - see next 2 posts

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Profile\LazyImport\{cf6a5c16-83b0-4d04-b702-195c35c6e887}
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\KeyBindingTables\{3AE79031-E1BC-11D0-8F78-00A0C9110057}
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Menus

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Packages\{cf6a5c16-83b0-4d04-b702-195c35c6e887}
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Services\{1C917A11-5B6E-4752-9DEC-94B041A05745}
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\ToolWindows\{3AE79031-E1BC-11D0-8F78-00A0C9110057}
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\UserSettings\Environment_Group\Environment_SolutionExplorer

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess.  Its the package that handles the Solution navigation.  So you can't get rid of it.  What it tells me is you have an add-on that might be to blame.  Why would use comments for that information?  You can edit your own question.....

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing Visual Studio 2013 from Control Panel, Programs and Features.